# What does "believe in" and "independence" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Do you believe in your partner’s independence? (Context: It's about dating)

I think it's somewhat odd to interpret literally. Does it mean "do you think that your partner can have his/her own space or lifestyle that is independent from yours"? What does "believe in" and "independence" exactly mean in this context? I think the definitions found in dictionary are too literal for this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you believe in something, you are certain that thing exists.

Independence is the ability to live your life without being helped or influenced by other people.

When you believe in your partner’s independence, you are confident about his/her financial/personal freedom.